# Restricting Android Application to Certain Screens

Tags: android

I'm developing a Live Wallpaper that requires the screen to be of certain features.

The Live Wallpaper should support API level 7 and above (Thought I'm not sure it'll work on Honeycomb) and `Normal` screen size with `Medium` density which are restricted to `HVGA(320x480)`, `WVGA800(480x800)`, `WVGA854(480x854)`

I am able to restrict it to `Normal` screen size using `support-screens` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<support-screens 
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="false" />
```

However, I have no idea how to restrict it to `Medium` density screen.

What is the best way to achieve this? as I don't want the wallpaper to appear in the Market for devices that could not run it.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify [`<compatible-screens>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html) in the manifest file, and the Market will not display your application for screens which are different from the ones you've listed as compatible.

```
<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Comment: According to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html that tag was introduced in API level 9, but I need to support API level 7 and above

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this, but given that basically the only purpose of this element is to trigger Market filtering, it shouldn't really matter what Android versions you're targeting.

Comment: I don't think so as the project won't compile with that tag as I'm also using `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />`

Comment: Just compile it against API 9.  As long as you don't use Java APIs that aren't on API 7 you will be fine.

Comment: Btw I VERY STRONGLY recommend not filtering your app like this.  You will cause a lot of confusion and unhappiness with users as your app is (seemingly randomly) not available on various devices.  Dealing with different densities is easy -- just scale your drawing.  For a live wall paper dealing with different sizes is probably easy as well as just scaling your drawing to the actual screen resolution will probably be totally fine.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll compile against API 9. My live wallpaper involves manipulating bitmaps, and scaling doesn't seem to produce the desired result. This is my first live wallpaper and would be my first app to be published in the Market, perhaps I should explore more before publishing it.